# How do I simply compile a C program for release with Visual C++ 2010 Express?

Tags: c, visual-c++, compiler-construction

I hope the answer to this question isn't too simple or obvious. I've been trying to get used to using a text editor and MinGW to compile some C code but I've found that I can't quite tear myself away from Visual C++ (mostly because of the IDE). The thing is, I've never used Visual C++ to just compile C/C++ into an executable; I always used the debugger and ran the program from inside Visual C++.

I just want to compile my program into a simple executable. How do I need to set up Visual C++ 2010 Express to do that? Don't I just set it to release mode and compile? Is there anything else I need to do (any settings I need to change)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've run the program in the debugger, then you've *already* compiled it!

Just find the executable in the correct folder. If it's a debug build, it'll be under Debug/, similarly for Release/

Note that you can't distribute a debug binary because it depends on the debug CRT which will only be available on a machine with VS installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run existing code that you have written then you can compile in debug or release mode in Visual Studio. You code will be compiled into an executable file that you can find in the Debug or Release folder in your project. Just double click this file to run it.

Now, if you compiled the debug version, it will be much bigger that the release version and it will (probably) link with debug versions of the C runtime and other VS DLLs. It will still run independently of the debugger though.

It is a common mistake to release or test an application that has been compiled in debug mode. The debug builds often don't expose some bugs as they run more slowly and the executable code is not optimised by the compiler.

If you want to write C appilcations, you can still use Visual studion - just write your code in files that you save as file.c not file.cpp. The compiler will figure it out.

If you want to write C code with a different IDE/compiler, I'd recommend Eclipse as an IDE and GCC as the compiler. MinGW is generally used to build applications that are targeted at Linux, you don't need it if you just want to write in C for a Windows platform.